# Is Wazzub a legitimate business opportunity?

Tags: economics

[Wazzub](http://www.wazzub.com) is a yet to be launched (at time of writing) web homepage, with advertising.

In order to recruit new members, they are offering a [MLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_marketing)-style payout to early adopters who recruit other users.

From their site:

[image]

The company has been [defending itself](http://heywazzub.blogspot.com.au/) against claims that it is a business with very little chance of meeting its goals, or even a scam.

Is there evidence that this company is legitimately able to offer the levels of profit to beginner users (for no money invested) that it claims?

---

Did the owner really launch the website on April 9, 2012?

Comment: The phrasing of the ad screams scam from a mile... Plus, for being an Internet phenomenon that gives you the perfect home page they have a very poor webpage. Better to stick to your perfect Google homepage :).

Comment: It's a lesser scam because they don't appear to be asking for money up front (if they are then run away!). All they are claiming is they will distribute profits to the people who refer most users. The catch is that if there are no profits then nothing will be distributed. And who gets to decide how much the 'profit' is? The company themselves. There is no explanation of how the 'potential earnings' are calculated.

Comment: Add to that the fact that they are claiming they are developing something that will be the 'best homepage ever' without explaining how they are going to do it.

Comment: It's ridiculous that the original question has downvotes when the answer to it has upvotes. Either the question is good and answerable or it isn't, you don't get to have both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a fairly standard MLM scam; though it uses recruiting an audience for advertisers to target, rather than application fees, to build the ponzi part of the process.

It proposes to be a new web portal. It has no evidence of any revenues. It's [competing](http://www.alexa.com/topsites) against [large incumbents](http://palatnikfactor.com/2010/02/16/facebook-becomes-the-largest-portal-on-the-web/) in the field.

It is demonstrably not the first profit-sharing site on the internet: indeed, there's a whole top-level domain dedicated to profit sharing sites: [.coop](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site:.coop&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

The proposal is that this site will earn revenue. That needs a lot of people to use the portal as their home page. Let's look at the design skills of the site owner, by looking at his blog. This is the man who's going to out-compete Google, Yahoo, MSN, AOL and a slew of other ISPs:

### Is this the web page of a successful web portal designer?

[image]

### No. No it isn't.

Comment: I can't provide better references, and I know that's the expected level of answer in this site. If this answer ends up below -2, I'll gladly delete it.